# Is there any REST API endpoint or graphql schema to get the product attributes only that are related to a specific category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, next.js, woocommerce-rest-api

**Problem**

I am using **Woocommerce Rest Api** with **Next JS** for building e-commerce site. I have successfully categorize the products but I also want to fetch only the **product attributes** that are related to that category, not all **product attributes** because some may be irrelevant and unecessary .

**REST API Endpoint**

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes` [This endpoint returns all the **product attributes**](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-product-attributes)

**Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "Camera Type",
    "slug": "pa_cameras",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Mobile Phone Brands",
    "slug": "pa_branded",
    "type": "select",
    ...
  },
  ... 
]
```

**What I want ?**

- It does not make any sense if I am on `/cameras` category page and I am getting `Mobile Phone Brands` filter (project attribute) on left sidebar.
- If I am on `/mobile-cases` category page, it should show only `Mobile Phone Brands` filter (project attribute) rather than both `Mobile Phone Brands` and `Camera Type`.
- Extra: It will be super good if I get `count` of total products in that filter (attribute) within selected category.

**Conclusion**

*I want REST API Endpoint or graphql schema that will help me to get product attributes with specific or selected category!*

[Documentation that I am following (Woocommerce Rest Api docs)](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-attributes)

Comment: I need this as well. Did you find a solution?